# python not detecting image

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm doing this simple python turtle program and for some reason, the program isn't detecting the image files. I ran the program in both VSCode and Repl and I'm having the error in both. I have double checked the image names along with their formats

```
#-----import turtle-----
import turtle as trtl

#-----setup-----
pear_image = "pear.png"
apple_image = "apple.png"

main = trtl.Screen()
main.setup(width=0.5, height=0.5)
main.bgpic("background.jpg")
main.addshape(pear_image)
main.addshape(apple_image)


pear = trtl.Turtle()
pear.shape(pear_image)
pear.penup()

apple = trtl.Turtle()
apple.shape(apple_image)
apple.penup()

#-----functions-----
# given a turtle, set that turtle to be shaped by the image file
def draw_pear(active_pear):
  active_pear.shape(pear_image)
  main.update()

def pear_down():
  pear.left(-120)
  pear.forward(100)


def draw_apple(active_apple):
  active_apple.shape(apple_image)
  main.update()

def apple_down():
  apple.left(-60)
  apple.forward(100)

def write_pear():
  main.goto(0,-80)
  main.pendown()
  main.color("yellow")
  main.write("Pear", font=("Arial", 74, "bold"))

def write_apple():
  main.goto(0,-80)
  main.pendown()
  main.color("red")
  main.write("Apple", font=("Arial", 74, "bold"))

#-----function calls-----

pear_down()

apple_down()

main.onkeypress(write_pear, "p")

main.onkeypress(write_apple, "a")

main.mainloop()
```

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: are you sure they're in the same directory as where your `main.mainloop()` is running?

Comment: care to include the exact error?

Comment: @BenPersonick sorry for that, it says it can't find the background.jpg file

Comment: @chrymxbrwn Yep

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the path for the image i think. like "c:/apple.png", make sure the slashers are the right way around.

Comment: I already tried that. It says "Bad arguments for register_shape". I think the issue is caused by python 3.9.0, I'm gonna switch back to 3.8.2 which is what I was using earlier to see if it works

Comment: The background picture (main.bgpic) function only can use .gif files. [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.bgpic)

Comment: Yep, not only that, there are some issues with python 3.8+ so I went back to 3.7 and used gif images and now it seems to work